# Nmap scan to discover devices connected to my router in C program

Tags: c, nmap

I am on a Linux computer. I am a complete novice in network programming. Therefore, I want to write a C program to discover devices connected to my router. It can simply be done by nmap by running `nmap -sn 192.168.1.1/24` in commandline. and it gives me the desired output.
[image: Result of running the command]

However, What I want is to collect these information in a string vector in C and print them. How can interact with nmap from C. I saw there is a way to use python3-nmap library but that is for python.

Comment: Since the core of `nmap` is written in C, you could use the [nmap c api](https://nmap.org/docs.html). This will probably require quite a bit of work. Alternatively, just launch the shell command from within your c code (e.g. using [system](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/)). You could let the shell command write into a temp file / stdin and then read form it in c.

Comment: `popen()` is a better approach than `system()` for reading a program's output.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently nmap does not have a C-API. it has python binding or its own scripting language known as NSE. Even though the program is partly written is C, there is no C binding to be found on their website.